# ns3.25/NetAnim Output/flomon

Tags: virtualbox

I am not able to see the output of NetAnim properly, Not able to see the parameters containing the values. I am running ns3.25 in ubuntu (64 bit) using Virtualbox. Please find the screenshot below.
[NetAnim Flomon output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MpaC.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Reduce the font size in the NetAnim window from 10 to 6 or some smaller number.
2. Hover the mouse over the border between the second and third panes in the NetAnim window until a two-sided left-right arrow appears and drag the second pane's border to the right to enlarge it until you can read all the text inside it.
3. Increase the size and resolution of the VirtualBox guest OS by downloading and installing VirtualBox Guest Additions. Open VirtualBox, select the Ubuntu guest OS, click the  gear-shaped *Settings* icon ⚙️ located on the VirtualBox menu bar, click *Storage*, click the dropdown triangle under the CD image to the right of where it says *Optical Drive*, and select *Choose Virtual Optical Disk File...*.

[image: VirtualBox]

4. Browse to the Guest Additions file that you downloaded from Oracle and select it. Start the Ubuntu guest OS. Install Guest Additions in the Ubuntu guest OS by accepting the VirtualBox Guest Additions prompt and then authenticating with your guest OS password. Save a snapshot of the Ubuntu guest OS before shutting it down to make the Guest Additions installation permanent.